# how to read array of numbers from text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file, multidimensional-array

I have written code as:

```
array = [[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]] 
fo = open("file.txt", "w")
fo.write(str(array))
fo.close()
```

That will save the array in .txt file, the content in the .txt file is in 2d array as:

`[[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]]`

And I want this array as it is back to the another program so that i can use this array for further calculation (the read array should not be a string)

Comment: Try [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

Comment: The term for what you're looking for is "serialization", and python provides many ways to do that, the most popular being pickle (for native python data) and json (for cross-platform data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import pickle

 numlist = [[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]] 

 outfile = open("log.txt", "wb")

 pickle.dump(numlist, outfile)

 outfile.close()

 infile = open("log.txt", "rb")

 pickle.load(infile)
 [[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]]
```

Comment: "accept it" is [hardly acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)

Comment: @Avinash Garg yes it is working but in txt file it is not loading in proper array pattern, it is showing as:(lp0
(lp1
F1.630217208498539
aa(lp2
F0.019929319226538452
aa. is there any way to correct it

Answer (score 0):

use [`ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evalute the string expression:

```
In [238]: import ast

In [241]: my_array=ast.literal_eval('[[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]]')

In [242]: my_array
Out[242]: [[1.630217208498539], [0.019929319226538452]]
```